# row_number not working on Querious (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

I tried on my Querious platform for MySQL to make a query that uses `row_number` and I didn't succeed. I tried many ways like this example.

```
SELECT
  row_number() over (partition by user_id order by session_date) as 'row',
  user_id,
  session_date
from engagements
```

wish you can find a solution :)

thanks!

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain what does "didn't succeed" means in detail. Also add a [example] and state the version of MySQL you're using.

Comment: Side note: Don't enclose aliases in single quotes.

Comment: @stickybit: "In the select list of a query, a quoted column alias can be specified using identifier or string quoting characters" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? What does `SELECT @@version;` return? If it's less than 8.0.2, then it doesn't support window functions.

Comment: @BillKarwin: Yes unfortunately MySQL allows that, I didn't claim it didn't. But that leads to people being used to put single quotes around any identifier and therefore questions like "Why does `SELECT 'nmuloc' FROM elbat`" not return the values in the table but just the literal... Or trying the same in other DBMS where that fails.

Comment: Yes, you can *define* an alias with a single-quoted string, but when you reference a column by its alias, you must treat it like an identifier. This is confusing, and that's why it's on the manual page about problems with aliases.

Comment: you right it's 5.7.26 version. what can I do if I don't have row number function